# how to sort array in decending order in php using data retrived from an API

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

im using an API  to get data from their server however im trying to sort that data in a descending order. Originally these messages are displayed with the oldest one first and the newest one last, right at the bottom  iv used arsort but it only displays the latest message and doesn't display any other previous messages, so just one message shows up

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this.. You need to more `arsort()` outside of the `foreach` construct.

```
    $arr = json_decode($response, true); 
    arsort ($arr['messages']);

    foreach($arr['messages'] as $message)
    { 
    echo ($message['number'])."<br />";echo ($message['message'])."<br />";echo ($message['date'])."<br /><br />"; 
    }
```

**`EDIT :`**

Sorting the date using `array_multisort`

```
foreach ($message as $k => $v) {
    $dtorder[$k]  = strtotime($v['date']);
}
array_multisort($dtorder, SORT_DESC, $message);
```

Comment: great! it displays the data :) one more little help I would like to sort this by the date how could I specify it to sort by date

Comment: How does your date look like ?

Comment: well to display date I use this: echo '($message['date'])' when its displayed its displayed like this: 2014-03-28 14:42:10

Comment: @user3433444, Since I don't have the data I just wrote a simple descending order sort function. It's not tested though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is interpreted like this:

```
foreach($arr['messages'] as $message) {
    arsort ($message);
}
echo ($message['number'])."<br />";echo ($message['message'])."<br />";echo ($message['date'])."<br /><br />";
```

because of where you placed your arsort call. Change it to this:

```
arsort ($message);
foreach($arr['messages'] as $message) {
    echo ($message['number'])."<br />";echo ($message['message'])."<br />";echo ($message['date'])."<br /><br />";    
}
```